# Rails 3: Can't create relationship :has_one

Tags: sql, mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a table User and a table Profile.

Here's what I have in User:

```
# Table name: users
#
#  id                   :integer         not null, primary key
#  email                :string(255)     default(""), not null
#  encrypted_password   :string(128)     default(""), not null
#  password_salt        :string(255)     default(""), not null
#  reset_password_token :string(255)
#  remember_token       :string(255)
#  remember_created_at  :datetime
#  sign_in_count        :integer         default(0)
#  current_sign_in_at   :datetime
#  last_sign_in_at      :datetime
#  current_sign_in_ip   :string(255)
#  last_sign_in_ip      :string(255)
#  created_at           :datetime
#  updated_at           :datetime
#  admin                :boolean
#

  has_one :profile
```

In profile:

```
# Table name: profiles
#
#  id           :integer         not null, primary key
#  user_id      :integer
#  organization :string(255)
#  phone        :string(255)
#  mobile       :string(255)
#  fax          :string(255)
#  address      :string(255)
#  city         :string(255)
#  zipcode      :string(255)
#  province     :string(255)
#  country      :string(255)
#  description  :text
#  url          :string(255)
#  skype        :string(255)
#  im           :string(255)
#  name         :string(255)
#  permalink    :string(255)
#  created_at   :datetime
#  updated_at   :datetime
#

  belongs_to :user
```

But when I try to run `User.find(3).profile.build(:user_id => 3)` or `User.find(3).profile.create(:user_id => 3)`I get the error that the method does not exist.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit**: `ruby-1.9.2-rc2 > Profile.create(:user_id => 10)` works well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
@user = User.find(3)
@profile = @user.build_profile()
```

This will create and associate the new profile but not save it.

Use this to save it also:

```
@user = User.find(3)
@profile = @user.create_profile()
```

See here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-association-reference

Comment: I have a   belongs_to :user in the Profile model. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: Have you tried `User.find(3).profiles.create(:user_id => 3)`? (plural profiles)

Comment: yes. ruby-1.9.2-rc2 > User.find(3).profiles.create(:user_id => 3)
NoMethodError: undefined method `profiles' for #<User:0x000001014b0f30>.